# What was the military equipment of a soldier of the Cholan Empire at its peak?

Tags: ancient-india

Well from what I've read, there is no specific mention to the sorts of equipment used by a Cholan soldier. There's really only info about how the army was structured. From descriptions of armies of later kingdoms belonging to the same region, most soldiers either wore no clothes, some form of clothed armor, or even chainmail. I've looked through some wikipedia articles and random internet forums to back up this info. Prolly not correct but that's why I've posted my queries here.
I guess a good start to finding the answer is to look at the equipment used in south-east asian kingdoms of the same era as they have been subjected to significant cholan influence.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: For example, did you look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chola_military)?

Comment: Well from what I've read, there is no specific mention to the sorts of equipment used by a Cholan soldier. There's really only info about how the army was structured. From descriptions of armies of later kingdoms belonging to the same region, most soldiers either wore no clothes, some form of clothed armor, or even chainmail. I've looked through some wikipedia articles and random internet forums to back up this info. Prolly not correct but that's why I've posted my queries here.

Comment: I guess a good start to finding the answer is to look at the equipment used in south-east asian kingdoms of the same era as they have been subjected to significant cholan influence.

Comment: @semipaiscuba I'm throwing him a bone because its not a major wikipedia page. I don't see what's so inherently wrong with this question, other than slang.

Answer (score 1):

> The government owns sixty thousand war elephants, every one seven or eight feet high. When fighting these elephants carry on their backs houses, and these houses are full of soldiers who shoot arrows at long range, and fight with spears at close quarters.-Zhao Rugua c. 1225

There was cavalry in addition to elephants. There is no evidence that the medieval Cholas used chariots; the iconic hindu symbol of battle.

Elephants were used to raise up the archers. These elephant carts would have captured the imagination of the Chinese geographer, but there were more numerous infantrymen on the ground, primarily armed with spears.

[Wikipedia- Chola Military](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chola_military)